# Postgres: "Recursive" query with Array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a database (that I can't change) one table looks like that:

```
| ID:integer | fk:integer | next:[integer array] |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 711        | {4}                  |
| 2          | 712        | {6}                  |
| 3          | 788        |                      |
| 4          | 799        | {7}                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now I try to define one Query that as first row the data with `ID = 1` and as next rows, all data with the `ID` that are in the integer array `next` (`{4}`) so that my query returns:

```
| ID:integer | fk:integer | next:[integer array] |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 711        | {4}                  |
| 4          | 799        | {7}                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

But then stops, so it only results the element with the specified `ID` and it's `next` elements.

I tried sth. like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT * FROM tablenm WHERE ID = ANY(SELECT next FROM tablenm WHERE ID = 1) AND ID = 1
```

The current Workaround I use is to first use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablenm WHERE ID = 1
```

And then for each element in the Array I run the same query with the `ID`s in a loop programmatically, but this looks like a dirty hack and I hope there is a solutions for this with 1 SQL statement.

Comment: You need to look into "Recursive CTEs"; I'd mock up an example, but I need to go and buy some food right now ;)

Comment: If you have another row like id = 7, next = {somthing}, do you need to put it into resultset as well? I mean is it true recursion or just 2 levels?

Comment: No, only the 2 levels, Daniels answer worked for me with `UNNEST`ing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`= ANY(array)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18479) in the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 ON t2.id = ANY(t1.next)
              OR t2.id = t1.id  -- add first row
WHERE  t1.id = 1                -- enter id to filter on once
ORDER  BY (t2.id <> t1.id);     -- "first row the data with ID = ?"
```

Should be fastest.
As @Daniel explained, *this* form (like your query) includes the first row only *once*.

If you want a "shorter query":

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 ON t2.id = ANY(t1.next || t1.id) -- append id to array
WHERE  t1.id = 1;  -- not sure if you need ORDER BY
```

Shorter, but not faster than the first form, because this will be expanded to an equivalent of the first form internally. Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

It should be noted that `next` can even be `NULL`, because:

```
SELECT NULL::int[] || 5  --> '{5}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I testst the speed and it's about 25% faster then the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't require recursion, just array un-nesting.

This should work:

```
select * from tablename where id=1
UNION ALL
select * from tablename where id
  in (select unnest(next) from tablename where id=1);
```

Comment: Thanks, `UNNEST` did the trick, got it a bit shorter: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=1 OR id IN (SELECT UNNEST(next) FROM tablename WHERE id=1)`

Comment: Yes. Just note the difference it introduces if/when `next` happens to contain `1` in its elements. The `UNION ALL` is specifically meant to output the id=1 row twice in this case, while the OR will produce it only once.